# GARCH(1,1) return model with dummy variables in the mean equation stata

Tags: stata, garch

I think this is a basic question but hope you can help because I think I am running this wrong in stata.

I am reseaching the hedging/diversification effects of various precious metal assets with the market(S&P500). I am using the following model

[image]

Equation 1 models the relation of the precious metal asset and stock market returns. The parameters are α_PM, β_0, β_1, β_2 and the error term is denoted by ε_t. r_(PMA,t) is the return on the precious metal investment asset and r_(m,t) is the return on the U.S. equity or the market. Two dummy variables are added to capture stock market volatility. They take a value of 1 if the market exceeds a certain volatility threshold given by the 5% (i.e., 〖Vol〗_q5), and 1% (i.e., 〖Vol〗_q1) quantiles of the return distribution.

The heteroscedasticity in the sample data is accounted for by the variance equation of the GARCH (1,1) model. In the second equation (σ_t^2) can be thought of as the one-period ahead forecast variance based on past information. The conditional variance is determined by three factors. A constant term, π. News about volatility from the previous period, e_(t-1)^2. And last period’s forecast variance, σ_(t-1)^2.

First up to create the returns:

```
    gen return_gold_bullion = log(gold_bullion)-log(L.gold_bullion)
    gen return_sp500 = log(sp500)-log(L.sp500)
    *creating volatility aquantile dummies*
    arch return_sp500, arch(1) garch(1)
    predict hgarch, variance
    tsline hgarch
    hist hgarch
    gen xx = sqrt(hgarch)
    sum xx, detail
    gen q1 = 0 
    replace q1 = 1 if xx >= 0.0412053
    gen q5 = 0 
    replace q5 = 1 if xx >= 0.0205247
    gen q5_mr = q5 * return_sp500
    gen q1_mr = q1 * return_sp500
    arch return_gold_bullion return_sp500 q5_mr q1_mr, arch(1) garch(1)
```

My question is if this is the right way to research te effect in stata for proposed model

Comment: Are you asking about the correctness of your code w.r.t. the model presented above? If so, this is off topic. If you have a statistical question, consider clarifying what it is.

Comment: Stackoverflow might be more suitable to ask this.